# What approaches/languages exist for describing network-protocols/packet-structures?

Tags: networking, network-programming, protocol-buffers, wireshark, ddl

There're simple structures of network protocols (e.g. **ipv4**, **tcp**, **udp**, ...) which can be can be easily described in any language via strictures. But there are more difficult structures with optional fields/block and dynamic block/field sizes (**TVL**, **LT**, etc.) - e.g. **ipv6**, **sctp**, **PROFINET-IO** (*decentralized periphery*), ...

My question is - How to properly describe the protocol data structure and store that for future using? E.g. generating structures for different languages, or getting all trees (e.g. in **ipv6** Wireshark *ipv6.opt.pdm.delta_last_recv*), or getting all fields for specific block/extension/option of the protocol.

I hope the description is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, an IPv4 header is a variable size (20 to 60), but an IPv6 header is always a fixed size of 40, and it is greatly simplified over the IPv4 header.

Comment: Wow. I missed that. Thanks a lot for this note. But as I know, IPv6 has extensions, which extend the IPv6 layer. Form this, IPv6 parser requires parsing-loop for the extensions. However, the question about description ways is opened. Maybe you know the way for describing a network protocol (in abstract language).

Comment: "_IPv6 has extensions, which extend the IPv6 layer._" Not exactly. The IPv6 extension headers are treated as payload, not part of the IPv6 packet header.. All the extension headers must be ignored by intermediate devices, e.g. routers, except the Hop-by-Hop Options, and those are largely ignored in the real world. The extension headers have their own protocol numbers, just like TCP and UDP, and the IPv6 header points to them exactly like it does for a transport protocol. They are more akin to ICMP, which is treated like a transport protocol, but it is an integral part of IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ASN1 language was created to solve this and other problems like it. IMHO, the reason that you do not see it used often is that the language got very complex and different factions started to use it in different ways (SNMP MIBs, Crypto X509, etc) which resulted in ASN1 compilers being specialized and not general.

Often instead of ASN1 you see a C-Struct definition of the packet or just an RFC packet diagram ( you can use the [protocol](http://www.luismg.com/protocol/) tool to generate one) with some markings (like `...`) to indicate variable length.

I guess [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) technically also qualifies as a language that describes a binary message though I do not believe it is a *general* language that can describe any message and is meant to be used by other protobuf-enabled applications.